# inverse regex match

Tags: regex, regex-negation

The data I am trying to filter is akin to the following list.

```
/sites/site1/archive/folder/
/sites/site1/archive/other/
/sites/site2/archive/folder/
/sites/site2/archive/other/
/sites/site3/other/folder/
/sites/site3/other/
/sites/site3/other/folder/location/
```

To match lines I wish to keep, I can successfully use `/.+sites\/.+\/archive\/folder.+/ig` (https://regex101.com/r/psxQum/2). This matches lines 1 and 3.

But to invert the selection, as in to match the lines that do not match my path, the *closest* (so far) I can come up with is `/.+sites\/.+\/archive\/(?!folder).+/ig` (https://regex101.com/r/psxQum/3) which matches lines 2 and 4, but not the 5.

*Edit1:*
I know I am searching for the literal match of `archive`, but when expanding the negative lookhead to include the archive folder `/.+sites\/.+\/(?!archive\/folder).+/ig`, it fails to match anything.

*Edit2:*
Included two more example patterns to list.

Comment: You're searching for the literal match of `archive` you'll never match line 5.

Comment: I understand this, which is why I said the "closest" to matching. If I expand the negative lookahead to include the archive folder (e.g. `/.+sites\/.+\/(?!archive\/folder).+/ig`) the regex fails, or I am missing something very obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://regex101.com/r/1zv3Hl/1

`.+sites\/.+\/(?!archive\/folder.+).+\/.+\/`

It's using negative lookahead to make sure that there's no `archive/folder` ahead, then matches "anything slash anything slash".  Because the two lines you don't want are excluded, only the remaining are matched.

Edit:  Changed from "0 or more" quantifier to the "1 or more" quantifier to match your established pattern.

2nd Edit based on comment:

Here's a completely different approach where you're matching any string so long as between the beginning and the end of the line, there's no instance of `archive/folder`.  If that pattern doesn't exist, the line will match.

`^(?:(?!archive\/folder).)*$`

https://regex101.com/r/BN82ce/1

Comment: Thanks! That works nicely.

What about if one of the paths was `/sites/site3/other/` instead of `/sites/site3/other/folder/`? Apologies I neglected that example.

Comment: No worries.  See edit.